# SQL Server vs MySQL -Query execution time difference

Tags: mysql

I have migrated a large MS SQL Server database to MySQL. I have noticed that query execution for complicated queries with multiple joins on MySQL takes considerably longer compared to SQL Server for the same query(125.063 sec vs 0.01 sec respectively). What could be causing this?

Comment: A thing that comes to the top of my mind: are you sure all your indexes have been migrated properly? I would see if you can dump out the execution plan and compare the two.

Comment: The engines are completely different. If you ported queries directly, you should expect differences. A number of other factora could be involved, such as indexes, server configuration, hardware, etc. This is an impossible question to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may caused by non-optimized queries for new DBMS. Or maybe you chosen bad mysql engine for example. Also, you have to be sure that ALL your indexes, primary keys, foreign keys and other have been imported successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Hast. Non of the indexes had been imported .So I recreated them again for a few test tables and the execution speed increased from 125sec to 0.5sec!